# [Doc error]"JAVA_HOME/lib/security" is under "JAVA_HOME/jre", but JDK 7's javadoc is misleading

Tags: java, security, javadoc, java-home

As [JavaSE 7 java.security JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getDefaultType()) suggests:

> ... The Java security properties file is located in the file named <<#JAVA_HOME>>/lib/security/java.security. <<#JAVA_HOME>> refers to the value of the java.home system property, and specifies the directory where the JRE is installed.

(# is for escaping)

It confuses me at first because:

1. If we have JDK installed, `JAVA_HOME` should point to `jdk_folder` and  `/lib/security/java.security` is found under `jdk_folder/jre`.
2. If we only have JRE installed, `/lib/security/java.security` is found under `jre_folder`.

So, the JavaDoc is ambiguous here. Maybe the term `JRE_HOME` is better. If I follow the JavaDoc to change the `JAVA_HOME` to be `jdk_folder\jre\`, it will all be messed up.

So some changes should be made in the JavaDoc. Where can I submit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Contact Us](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/feedback.html) page to find the email address to submit corrections:

> If you find any errors or have any other suggestions for improvement, please mail javasedocs_us@oracle.com and indicate the complete URL of the relevant page.

**References**

- [[JDK-8026474] deployJava.js versioncheck doesn't work in IE11 - Java Bug System](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8026474)